# Java 2D Sidescroller Terrain

Tags: java, noise

I am making a sidescoller game to learn more java and practice. But I have come to a poitn where  I have lots of questions and I dont know how to implement things to the code.
I´ve already searched about Noise and the basics behind it. I found some code about Simplex Noise but I was unable to implement it, also i dont know if I was doing it right

First: I would like to generate random terrain.Which is the best way? Simplex Noise? Fractal?
Perlin Noise? 1D or 2D?

Then How would I implemnt the things above? Is there any Java library for generating noise or any code example?

Thanks

Edit:Here is the main question how I can implement a Noise function to make a sidescroller Terrain.

Comment: You are asking too many questions at once. As for noise, specifically: The best way depends on the type of terrain you're trying to generate. Design some test software that lets you select an algorithm, then try all the algorithms and see what you like. Implementations of all of the noise algorithms you mentioned can be easily found on the internet, and wikipedia has decent overall descriptions if you'd like to implement them from scratch as an exercise.

Comment: There seem to be some general implementations in [bukkit](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/util/noise/NoiseGenerator.html); although you are generally working with 1D noise, not 2D. Also check out some of the related links on the right side of this page.

Answer (score 2):

**Perlin Noise** is a good starting point to create fractal terrains (2d or 3d). I recommend reading [Hugo Elias's tutorial](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), which explains the theory and also provides pseudo code for a noise generator and fast pseudo random numbers.

Perlin Noise can be used to generate fractal terrains **from scratch**, but using the same technique it's also possible to **fractalize pre-formed terrains** (for example a painted height map which defines the basic terrain with valleys and peaks).
For more realistic results, the outcome can be post-processed (simulated erosion, etc.).

Comment: Okay, So I read the article But i cannot pass the pseudo-code to Java, also I did not find a way to apply it, Should I make a 1D Noise to get the height of X?